# Using Stored Procedure to Update an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The stored procedure is a pre-existing procedure used by the front-end application. The `worklist` table is a custom table that was added when specific events happen in the application and I then need to update a `Translation` table once the `worklist` is edited.

I do not know how to pass the values from the `worklist` table to the stored procedure. I would also like to write the current date/time to the `UpdateTime` column in the `worklist` table.

The columns in the `worklist` table are:

```
ID, TransTableID, Source1, Source2, Source3, Target, UpdateTime
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTranslationTableValues]
    @id     integer output,
    @tableid int,
    @input1 varchar(255),
    @input2 varchar(255),
    @input3 varchar(255),
    @output varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    /*BEGIN TRAN*/

    IF @id!=0
        UPDATE TranslationTableValues
        SET TableID = @tableid, TableInput1 = @input1, TableInput2 = @input2, TableInput3 =       @input3, TableOutput = @output
        WHERE TableEntryID = @id
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT into TranslationTableValues 
        VALUES (@tableid, @input1, @input2, @input3, @output)

        SELECT @id = @@identity
    END

    IF @@error!=0
    BEGIN
       /*     if @@nestlevel = 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    ELSE
        COMMIT TRAN  */

    SELECT @id = 0

    RETURN -2
END

/*COMMIT TRAN*/ return @id

END
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want to achieve, be more specific, add an example if possible.

Comment: I want to use the posted SP to INSERT into TranslationTableValues 
        VALUES (tableid, input1, input2, input3, output).  Sample values to insert are, table ID = 1145, input1 = 1234, input 2 = 4567, input 3 = "", output = "Translated Value".

Comment: and what it's wrong with the sp itself, it looks like it does the insert/update into the table.